# Do i need to learn DataSet?

Tags: linq-to-sql, dataset

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533/c-what-else-do-you-use-besides-dataset) question i am clear that `DataSet` is an old Technology. Now people use `Linq to SQl`. I am new to databas programming and learning these concepts. My question is do i need to learn `DataSet` first then move to `Linq to SQL` or i can directly jump to the later one. 

In future a problem could come where i have to use only `DataSet`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ to SQL does not depend on DataSets. Don't learn them.

You might even want to skip ahead to Entity Framework because L2S is abandoned (alas!) by Microsoft. EF is the declared future.

Don't ever learn a predecessor technology first if you are actually interested in the successor. Learning materials for successor technologies make sure you get to know everything that is important. If DataSets were important your learning materials would tell you so.

Comment: Then why is that some book authors give a full detail of a predecessor technology. I am studying Professional C# by WROx. Entity Framework is included in the new addition of this book but before EF there a full chapter for DataSet(DataTables,Datacolumns,Datarows,creating schemas by coding, by database,by XSD). Why they give so explanation when earlier versions cover the predecessor technology?

Comment: Who knows? Don't read that. Some people need to know that because at their jobs they use old stuff in legacy applications.